# how to start a installed service wth powerhell and set the startup type for that service

Tags: powershell

i want to start a service with a certain name eg. test.
the things i need to do is:

1. check if service is installed
2. change startup type to automatic
3. start the service

i have tried the following command but that is not working:
get-service testAM* | Set-Service -name testAM* -StartupType automatic |Start-Service TestAM*

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track already. `Set-Service` is one of those cmdlets that consumes the object once completed. So, you just have to tell it to move on down the pipeline using `-Passthru`.

```
Get-Service -DisplayName testAM* | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic -PassThru | Start-Service -PassThru
```

There's also no need to re-specify the name on `Set-Service` as it accepts the object being output by `Get-Service`. InputObjects accepted by `Set-Service` are as follows:

- *System.String*
- *System.String[]*
- *System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController*

Take a look at `Get-Help Get-Service -ShowWindow`, and `Get-Help Set-Service -ShowWindow` to see how I got the objects that it accepts, just scroll down to "**Inputs**", and "**Outputs**".

**EDIT:**
Just saw you'd like to check if they exists. You can add some simple `if(){}`, and `else{}` logic:

```
$Service_Name  = "testAM*"
$Test_Services = Get-Service -DisplayName $Service_Name
    if($Test_Services){
        #$Test_Services | Set-Service -StartupType Automatic -PassThru | Start-Service -PassThru
        foreach($Service in $Test_Services){
            "$($Service.DisplayName) exists!"
            #or:
            #Slower way of setting the service and starting them
            #Set-Service -InputObject $Service -StartupType Automatic -PassThru | Start-Service -PassThru
        }
    } else {
        "No services with name '$Service_Name' exist!:("
    }
```